# Memory Management Issue with CoreData

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, memory-management, autorelease

Note: This question has been completely re-organized due to so many down votes.

I am displaying a UITableViewController using NSFetchedResults with core data.
It displays fine, but when I push a new view controller and the user uses the back button to navigate back to the UITableView its crashes with that error.

I have been battling this for weeks and have not figured out why. I can tell that its likely related to memory management but I cant find it anywhere.

**Update:** Using Instruments-Zombies I found out that in fact it was crashing on CoreData -`prepareResultsForResultsSet`. See image 
[image]
Here is the code from my FetchedResultsController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

NSManagedObjectContext *thecontext;
thecontext = [(Logix_AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TimeOff" inManagedObjectContext:thecontext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeOffStartDate" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:thecontext sectionNameKeyPath: @"timeOffType" cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
[sort release];
[fetchRequest release];
[theFetchedResultsController release];
return fetchedResultsController;    
}
```

Comment: `autorelease` is just a delayed `release`.  If you have a memory management problem, substituting `release` for `autorelease` is just going to make it fail faster.  If you can, turn on ARC.

Comment: The title is weird for this question

Comment: You shouldn't be autoreleasing the UIImage in this instance.  You should never release/autorelease an object unless you did both an alloc AND and init of some sort.   Anything that returns an object with first allocing it is going to be returning a autoreleased object already (for example the *imagedNamed:* method above).

Comment: @Daij-Djan. I was getting an error that I didnt understand so I called the question name the exact error so its unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you copy/paste the actual error from Xcode?  And backtrace of where the crash happens, if any?

You definitely should not be `autorelease`ing the object returned by `+imageNamed:`;  that object is already autoreleased.

---

Your comment:

> iVacationTimeApp[47892:19d03] **-[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x95c9140**

There is your answer.  You have an overreleased object.   May be the `image`, might be something else.   Turn on Zombie detection in Instruments and run again.

Comment: In the console is this: iVacationTimeApp[47892:19d03] *** -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x95c9140

Comment: The code posted in the question is the last line that works. This is what I see when it breaks: 0x204fa97:  calll  0x2133a00                 ; symbol stub for: getpid    Highlighted is Thread 1: EXC BREAKPOINT

Comment: Doesn't matter that `getpid` is highlighted;  that was likely simply the thread that ended up handling the exception.  The error message itself is quite clear as to what is going on;  you are over-releasing an object.   Turn on zombies and reproduce the issue!

Comment: @bburn, thanks. I am looking at the code to see where I over released something. I have Zombies turned on and I cleared the issue with the image but it still crashes at the same place.  My next project I am going to start with ARC.

Comment: What did zombies tell you?  I.e. where was the object that was over-released created?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I got busy with another app and just getting back to this. So I run the Zombies in Instruments and it breaks on CoreData -PrepareResultsFromResultsSet. Basically when I select UITableViewCell it shows a detail of that information. Whem I use the UINavigationBar to go backwards it crashes every time.

Comment: any ideas. I am at a loss here.

Comment: Instruments will tell you what is overreleased... it is up to you to figure out why.  There are a number of tutorials on this subject via google searches and a number of high fidelity answers on SO.   Dive in.   If you can't fix the issue after gathering more details, post the details as a new question.